# android　resもしくはassetsに置いたrawファイルを、ファイルパスを引数とする関数に渡したい

Tags: android, java

ファイルシステムのファイルパス文字列を引数に取るfunc(String filePath)という関数の引数にresもしくはassetsに置いたrawファイルを与えることはできるのでしょうか？
その場合のコードを教えて頂けませんでしょうか。

JSchというjavaのssh/sftpライブラリ（https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/）をandroid上で利用しようとしています。
sshサーバーは公開鍵認証方式です。
PC上のjavaでは下記のコードで動作しました。
これをandroid上のコードにしようとしています。
秘密鍵をresもしくはassetに置いてJSch#addIdentityに読ませたいのですが、そのコードをお教え頂けませんでしょうか。

```
final String identityKeyFileName = "PATH/TO/ID_RSA";
final String passPhrase = "PASSPHRASE";
final String userId = "USER"
final String hostname = "HOSTNAME";
final int port = 22;

final JSch jsch = new JSch();

// HostKeyチェックを行わない
Hashtable config = new Hashtable();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
jsch.setConfig(config);

// 鍵追加
jsch.addIdentity(identityKeyFileName, passPhrase );

// Session設定
final Session session = jsch.getSession(userId, hostname, port);
final UserInfo userInfo = new SftpUserInfo();
```

Comment: そもそも何故path(`String`)として渡したいのかという点と、JavaなのかKotlinなのかを**質問に追記**されるとより良い回答が付くかもしれません。(型の位置的にJavaかと思いましたが)

Comment: リソースとして読み取ることになると思います(1ファイルとしてファイルシステム上に存在するわけではなく、.apkにアーカイブされているので)。同様の質問に対する回答が[こちら](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36589520/4506703)にあるようです。

Comment: yukihane様、ありがとうございます。  
下記のコードがヒントなのでしょうが、理解できません。  
privateKeyByteStreamはどこで利用されているのでしょうか？  
"private_key_without_extension"は秘密鍵のファイル名から拡張子を除いた部分でしょうが、"anyIdentityName"は何でしょうか？  
privateKeyBytesは秘密鍵ファイル内容の文字列でしょうか？  
publicKeyBytesは公開鍵ファイル内容の文字列でしょうか？  
  
InputStream privateKeyByteStream = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier("private_key_without_extension", "raw", getPackageName()));  
jSch.addIdentity("anyIdentityName", privateKeyBytes, publicKeyBytes, passphrase);

Comment: ちょっと気になったので念のため。そもそもresやassetの中身は外部から比較的容易に見ることが出来たと思いますが、その辺りは大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: 「resやassetの中身は外部から比較的容易に見ることが出来た」ということでしたら見直しです。アブリ専用のdata/data/に格納した方がよいのかな。

Comment: androidでは秘密鍵の安全な保管場所はなかなかないようですね。Android Keystore Systemというものがあるようですがビギナーには難しいようです。

Comment: ええ。そのままアプリの内部に組み込んで公開する安全な方法は無いと思います。そもそも.apkファイルは、.zipに書き換えればそのまま展開できますから。javaのコードもツールで簡単に逆コンパイルできますので、ここへ組み込んでも安全ではありません。一応できなくもない方法がありますが、AndroidNDKを使い、難読化したC/C++のコードに秘密鍵を入れ、さらに攪乱用の無意味な配列も大量に用意し、XORなどの演算を複数回かませて計算結果として秘密鍵を得るような手法です。ただ、労力が半端ない上に完全ではないです。Android Keystore Systemは比較的安全に暗号化を施せますが、今回の場合は鍵の配送手段が問題ですね。これは主にログイントークンなどを暗号化するのに使います。